# Will the deletion of file from hdfs also deletes the file from the replicated datanodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In order to free up the memory space, I'm planning to delete some of the files from hdfs. I have a 3 node cluster.

If I delete a file from hdfs, will it automatically delete the file from the replicated datanodes also?

Comment: Well, did you try it? What have you observed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is deleted from replicated datanodes too, but it takes some time. To delete file immediately without trash use -skiptrash flag.
This [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html) is useful too:

> When a file is deleted by a user or an
>   application, it is not immediately removed from HDFS. Instead, HDFS
>   first renames it to a file in the /trash directory. The file can be
>   restored quickly as long as it remains in /trash. A file remains in
>   /trash for a configurable amount of time. After the expiry of its life
>   in /trash, the NameNode deletes the file from the HDFS namespace. The
>   deletion of a file causes the blocks associated with the file to be
>   freed. Note that there could be an appreciable time delay between the
>   time a file is deleted by a user and the time of the corresponding
>   increase in free space in HDFS.
>
> A user can Undelete a file after deleting it as long as it remains in
>   the /trash directory. If a user wants to undelete a file that he/she
>   has deleted, he/she can navigate the /trash directory and retrieve the
>   file. The /trash directory contains only the latest copy of the file
>   that was deleted. The /trash directory is just like any other
>   directory with one special feature: HDFS applies specified policies to
>   automatically delete files from this directory. The current default
>   policy is to delete files from /trash that are more than 6 hours old.
>   In the future, this policy will be configurable through a well defined
>   interface.